# Show fix 4 flex box in one row

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, ngfor

The main target is I would like to show fix 4 boxes in one row.I would like to show like that=>

```
 <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
        <box></box>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have boxes array like that=>

```
<box *ngFor="let info of infolist;let i = index"></box>
```

but this one shows like that=>

```
   <div class="flex-container">
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
   </div>
```

here is my css=>

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    justify-content: center; 
}

.flex-container .flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

How can I show fix 4 `flexbox` in one row?

Comment: Do you only need to achieve visual effect of four boxes in row? Or you need to have HTML structure like in your first block of code?

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk, If I can do it like HTML structure like the first block, It gonna be great. I already tried `innerHTML`. But cant gets like that and I have almost 200 boxes. Calling this function makes slow to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage chunks pipe like:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'chunks'
})
export class ChunksPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(arr: any, chunkSize: number) {
    return arr.reduce((prev, cur, i) => (i % chunkSize) ? prev : prev.concat([arr.slice(i, i + chunkSize)]), []);
  }
}
```

with the following template:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-row" *ngFor="let chunk of infoList | chunks: 4">
       <box *ngFor="let box of chunk">{{box}}</box>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Stackblitz Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-flnzvx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Or you can rethink your HTML structure and just use flat structure with `width: 25%` for each `box`.

Comment: This is a great solution, actually. I don't know why it got downvoted...

Comment: @yurzui, It's awesome. Let me try it. Thanks. Box width is fix can't resize. So can't assign like %.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: have added one more answer based on float.

```css
box {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

box:nth-child(4n + 1){
  background-color: lightblue;
  clear: both;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
  <box></box>
</div>
```

The Key is to calculate the width based on the available width. This can be done with `width: calc(100% /4);`.

Note: `box-sizing: border-box;` is important if you are giving any border. In other box-sizing, borders will get added to your width and the above calc will not work.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}

box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(100% /4);
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
     <box></box>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks but box width is fix can't resize, and not depend on screen size. So I can't put like % to box width.